# Dataflow job failed: IP_SPACE_EXHAUSTED, IP space of is exhausted

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

An error in the log:

```
Startup of the worker pool in zone region-d failed to bring up any of the desired 1 workers.
IP_SPACE_EXHAUSTED: IP space of 'projects/project-x/regions/region-y/subnetworks/default' is exhausted.
```

We have disable usage of public IPs and use private ones.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was increase amount of IP available in the subnet.

E.g. by changing a subnetwork mask (size):

Go to `VPC network`/ Edit your subnetwork `default` / Edit `IP address range`

```
x.y.z.a/20 => x.y.z.a/18.
```